# Firebase cloudfunction functions.config() returns an empty object in production

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to access the token stored in `functions.config().fb.token` but `functions.config()` returns an empty object.

To create the token I've generated it using the following command:

```
firebase login:ci
```

And later I deploy the generated token using the following command:

```
firebase deploy --token "PREVIOUSLY_GENERATED_TOKEN"
```

But the cloud function always return and empty object when calling `functions.config()` in production.

What shall I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you run the following command in the Firebase CLI?

- `firebase use your_production_project_id_or_alias`
- `firebase functions:config:set fb.token="Your Token"`

Could you try to run the following command in the Firebase CLI?

- `firebase use your_production_project_id_or_alias`
- `firebase functions:config:get`

If you set correctly then your config is displayed in your terminal.

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli

Comment: Following your instructions I can access the token, thanks!